# How to implement basic LOD mechanism on a 3D json asset

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I am not able to implement LOD to a 3d Object with json data.
Here is my implementation:

```js
loader.load('models/robot-threejs/robot.json', function(object){
    var lod = new THREE.LOD(object);

    for (var i=1; i<=3;i++) {
        console.log("this"+i);
       lod.addLevel(object,i);
         }

         lod.updateMatrix();
  lod.matrixAutoUpdate = false;

    //     lod.updateMatrix();
    //     lod.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
        
        scene.add(lod);
     //scene.add(object);
    // object.position.set(30, 30, 30);
    
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're implementing `THREE.LOD` wrong.

1. The constructor does not take any parameters, so when you do this: `new THREE.LOD(object);`, it does nothing. You just have to use `new THREE.LOD();`
2. You're adding the same mesh to LOD 3 times, so you're not gonna see any difference. You need to create separate meshes with different geometries if you want to see any change in detail. Keep in mind that you have to generate these geometries yourself. Three.js doesn't automatically change the geometry for you. But you could use the [SimplifyModifier](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=modifi#webgl_modifier_simplifier) for this.
3. Not sure why you're playing with matrix updates. There's no reason for this here.
4. You also need to call `lod.update(camera)` on your render loop if you want to see the change in detail.

I strongly recommend you read [the documentation for LOD](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/objects/LOD) and read through the code in [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_lod) to better understand how it works.